# Using Paypal Express Checkout digital goods with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to implement Paypal's digital goods express checkout on a Codeigniter website.

I am using mod rewrite to take the index.php out of the Codeigniter URLs, and so when Paypal does a call back to my website with ?token=xxxx appended on the end, I get a 404 error.

The flow of events gets stuck when Paypal does this callback to the website. The pop up appears but just stays on "loading...".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have just changed the uri_protocol in the config file to be:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

And now I can access $_GET variables, but the window that pops up still wont go any further past "loading...".

Comment: is the pop up at PayPal side?

Comment: It pops up a window with the URL of my website in the address bar, but then that is supposed to forward to Paypal.

Comment: OK, so I misunderstood the point. I thought, you redirect the user from your site to PayPal login site, then after user login and confirms payment, returning back to your site fails. Is this corect?

Comment: Not quite, I am implementing the sales flow detailed here: [link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_IntegratingExpressCheckoutDG). I send my form to a method that does a remote call to Paypal, this returns a token. The window that pops up over my site is supposed to then redirect to paypal using that token - but it just doesn't.

Comment: Also, I should add I have got this working using just PHP - it's the fact that I'm using it all in Codeigniter that's the problem.

Comment: Which api function do you call during this redirect?

Comment: Is this still unresolved? I might be able to help

Answer (score 1):

Use the CI Merchant library written by Adrian Macneil http://ci-merchant.org/

It not only supports Paypal Express, but many other payment services.

In the test code provided with the library, it gives you an example of how to use PayPal.